# Accessing site with certificate and username/pwd to webscrape

Tags: c#, httpclient, x509certificate2

I am trying to access a financial website Finra thru c# code in the hopes to scrape data. The site requires a certificate which I have and a username/password before navigating to the page. As of now I have created a console application which I call the GetRequest method in the main function:

```
 async static void GetRequest(string url)
    {
        try
        {

            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 100000000;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            {
                return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
            X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate();
            WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
            requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

            NetworkCredential nwCredentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            requestHandler.Credentials = nwCredentials;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler))
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(myContent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

the certificate function is :

```
 private static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
    {
        X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "xxxxxxx", false);

            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
            if (findResult.Count == 1)
            {
                clientCertificate = findResult[0];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to locate the correct client certificate.");
            }
            return clientCertificate;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            userCaStore.Close();
        }
    }
```

My issue is that when I run the code and get to the line `client.GetAsync(url)` I get an error in the catch exception

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have looked around and I saw other posts recommend putting in ServerCertificateValidationCallback event and return true in the body, but that doesn't solve the issue since it just bypasses the certification and I get access denied when getting html. I looked at the "errors" variable and saw Im getting RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

> System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            {
                return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
```

Which I dont understand because in the GetClientCertificate() I am getting the certificate by name as well as by thumbprint and checked the values in the return object and seem to check out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might try this in a browser first, and monitor the entire exchange including headers in the debugger window and see what you're missing.

Comment: @Terry Carmen I opened up chrome with the debugger window network panel. I copied the values from Request Header section and set it to the HttpWebRequest variable and ran it I got an error of "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." Any idea?

Comment: Something is different between the browser's behavior and your app. You might consider setting up Wireshark and see exactly what is different.

Comment: @JoeyDiaz - Why, on Earth, do you do `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Does your comment have anything to do with the question I asked. I doubt the throw exception on a sample project have anything to do with why I am unable to log in with certs and network cred. I mean if you can explain your why on earth comment to me bec maybe I'm dense

Comment: @JoeyDiaz - I'm just saying that that kind of code make your code harder to test, it slows things down, it's harder to refactor, and takes longer to code. It just doesn't add any value. I struggle to understand why so many developers feel the need to `try`/`catch` like that. In my opinion we should only ever catch **specific exceptions** that we can **meaningfully handle**. `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` and `catch { throw; }` are not specific and they are not meaningful.